# Building an incomplete redox half reaction/reduction

Tags: redox, carbonyl-compounds

I can't seem to figure out this redox reaction.

$$
\ce{CH3COO- + CO2 -> CH3CH2COO-}
$$

Is the charge on the carbon in the $\ce{CO2}$ supposed to match the charge on the carbon in the $\ce{CH3COO-}$? I am supposed to build a half reaction using $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{H+}$ as needed, but I can't seem to figure out how many electrons are actually transferred. What are the charges on the carbon?

Answer (score 4):

It helps to use "fully compressed" formulae so you can easily count atoms and figure out how to balance carbons, oxygens, hydrogens, and charges.  That is, instead of

- $\ce{CH3COO- +CO2 -> CH3CH2COO-}$

write it this way:

- $\ce{C2H3O2- +CO2 -> C3H5O2-}$

Then it's easy to see that this is not a balanced equation.  Carbon atoms are the same on each side, but not oxygen or hydrogen atoms.  You need two more $\ce{O}$ atoms on the products side.  Those have to come from water since that is the only oxygen-containing species you are allowed to use.

- $\ce{C2H3O2- +CO2 -> C3H5O2- + 2H2O}$

Now oxygen is balanced, but hydrogen is still imbalanced.  That can be rectified by adding $\ce{H+}$ into the equation as appropriate.

- $\ce{C2H3O2- +CO2 +6H+ -> C3H5O2- + 2H2O}$

Now only charge is imbalanced, which can be fixed by adding electrons to complete the balanced half-reaction:

- $\ce{C2H3O2- +CO2 +6H+ +6e- -> C3H5O2- + 2H2O}$